# Enabling Bluez Kernel Logs in Android source code

Tags: android, logging, bluetooth, android-source, java.util.logging

I am working on Bluetooth application and need to get the native Bluez stack.

Can any one give any pointers to do so? I have complete source code with me so if I need to modify any file and build the code again then that will also help.

Thnaks in Advance.

Swapnil

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG is set as "CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y" in your config file.
2. start the complete build and flash the binary images to the target.
3. Open ADB command prompt and type the following sequence of commands:

   - Mount debugfs interface
     adb shell "mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug"
   - Enable Debug logs for the module
     adb shell "echo -n \"file  +p\" > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control"
   - Save Kernel Logs
     adb shell "cat /proc/kmsg > sdcard/myl2cap.log"

Cheers